# Ionic cordova file transfer upload works in Android and iOS simulator, but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

We have been using file-transfer for a while in our Ionic App and it has been smooth, but recently it has stopped working on iOS devices, however it still works in the XCode Simulator and on Android devices.

Here is the relevant part of the FileService class:

```
 export class FileService {
```

`` enviandoArquivo: boolean = false;

  transfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();
  constructor(private fileTransfer: FileTransfer, private file: File, private fileChooser: FileChooser,
    private camera: Camera, private photoViewer: PhotoViewer, private fileOpener: FileOpener, private authService: AuthService,
  private platform: Platform) { }

  uploadFileFromChat(pathFromLibrary: string, chatId: string, tipoChat: TipoChat, emailUsuario: string) {
    this.enviandoArquivo = true;
    let data = new Date();
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      chunkedMode: false,
      fileKey: 'file',
      fileName: this._obterNomeArquivo(pathFromLibrary),
      headers: { 'chatId': chatId, 'dataDeEnvio': data.toLocaleString(), tipoChat: tipoChat, email: emailUsuario,
      'external_login_token': this.authService.AccessToken},
      mimeType: "multipart/form-data"
    }

    return this.transfer.upload(pathFromLibrary, `${SharedInformation.URL_BASE}Mensagem/Imagem/`, options, true)
    .then((a: FileUploadResult)=> {
      this.enviandoArquivo = false;
      return JSON.parse(a.response)}, err => {
        return this.enviandoArquivo = false;
      }).catch(err => {
        return this.enviandoArquivo = false;        
      });
  } ``

The problem lies in the `transfer.upload()` method. When it is called, it never registers any response; None to the App, none to the Server, we use Rollbar on both sides and neither register anything, and none of the error callbacks on the method are fired. So the app is stucking forever uploading.

I tried using `transfer.abort()` and still there was no error callback, it is as if the upload never ends, and thus there's nos response as the method hasn`t finished yet.

Comment: Fonteless The best way is to debug the app using device debug option in safari. Once I had such issue in Android device, finally got to that the build process has included some special characters for copy pasted code resulted in the error.

Comment: I have already tried debugging it many times, the problem is that the debugger never fires on neither the .then() nor the .catch(). You're saying i should go into the plugin's method itself?

Comment: Ya that could be an option as it may fail if the error is not handled in plugin itself